# PIC18 Global Interrupt Enable bit toggling when keypad button pressed

Tags: c, microcontroller, interrupt, pic, interrupt-handling

#### Objective

I am trying to interface a 4x3 matrix keypad and 7 segment LED display to PIC18f4550 microcontroller. When I press buttons on keypad, I want the 7 segment display to show the number accordingly.

---

#### What I have done so far

Based on my research, I can either use scanning (continuously polling) or use interrupts to interface the keypad with the MCU. I decided to use interrupts as that way the microcontroller can be free up for other operations.

The following is the connection of keypad to MCU.

[image]

I am using RB0-2 as input to MCU and RB4-7 are set as output from MCU. RB4-7 are permanently set high so when the user press on the keypad button, it will trigger the RB0-2(INT0-INT2) interrupt to process.

**For simplicity in this post, I will only discuss about the Column 1 of the keypad.**

This is how I initialize and setup the registers.

```
void main(void)
{
OSCCON = 0x72;
TRISD = 0;
LATD = 0;
ADCON1 = 0x0F;
 
TRISB = 0x07;
LATB = 0xF0;// keep the RB4-7 high

INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
INTCONbits.INT0IF = 0;
INTCONbits.INT0IE = 1;
INTCON2bits.INTEDG0 = 1;

while (1);
}
```

My interrupt handling is as below:

```
if(INTCONbits.INT0IF == 1)
{
    for(char scan=0x10; scan>=0x80; scan <<= 1) // send 1 to each row starting from RB4 till RB7
    {
        LATB = scan;        
        if (PORTBbits.RB0 = 1) 
        {
            if(scan == 0x10)
            {
                display_number(1); 
            }
            if(scan == 0x20)
            {
                display_number(4);
            }
            if(scan == 0x40)
            {
                display_number(7);
            }
        }
        
    }
    LATB = 0xF0;
    INTCONbits.INT0IF == 0;
```

---

#### My problem

When I run the simulation, I noticed that the GIE bit keep toggling very fast between 0 and 1 as soon as I press on any button in Column 1 and no display of any number on 7segment as well. I added the watch window screenshot and highlighted the GIE bit that is toggling.

[image]

What have I done wrong? Is my logic of handling interrupt flawed?

---

#### UPDATE 1

As DavidHoadley suggested, I have changed to use use `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

I have also corrected the for loop condition.

What I observed was, If I keep the loop inside the interrupt routine, the loop will get stuck for some reason.

For now, I have given up trying to use loop inside the interrupt function and instead resort to have a function in main while loop to output high at each row sequentially forever and the interrupt function is only used to check the output using `switch statement`.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop end condition looks like the loop will immediately exit. The line:

```
for(char scan=0x10; scan>=0x80; scan <<= 1)
```

Should probably be:

```
for(char scan=0x10; scan<=0x80; scan <<= 1)
```

Can’t test this - hope it works

Comment: I tried changing as you suggested but now the loop doesn't seem to stop. It just keep on going forever.

Comment: Print the value each tme round the loop? The condition `>=` was definitely wrong. Can you add `break` if any of the comparisons with `scan` is true?

Comment: I basically removed the for loop and type out the conditions manually for each case but the issue remains. I think the "condition" aside, somewhere else is wrong.

Comment: If you are doing bit-shift operations, you should really use an unsigned variable. Try declaring `scan` as type `uint8_t` rather than `char`. Or if your compiler is a C89 compiler (which it very well could be) and `uint8_t` is not already defined for you, either just declare `scan` as `unsigned char`, or define `uint8_t` yourself, with `typedef unsigned char uint8_t`. This might also fix your problem with the loop not terminating.

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal behaviour for PIC micros. When PIC goes to the interrrupt vector the GIE bit reset by hardware and when it finishes servicing the interrupt, it returns with the `RETFIE` assembly instruction by setting the GIE bit which is not visible in C code. So there is no fault in your code for this matter, this is not even a matter.

I see in your code you are using only INT0 interrupt to detect presses and the rest of INTx pins are not activated. That's why the PIC micro will be able to detect the changes of the only first column. I suggest you to use interrupt on change (IOC) which features on RB<7:4> bits. This way you can free the INTx pins for other purposes. And you can move the 3 pins to a PORT other than PORTB. Here is the procedure or my suggestion if you interest:

- Configure RB<7:4> pins as inputs and enable their IOC feature.
- Configure any 3 pins as output of any port.
- If you use the positive logic set the 3 pins high otherwise, low.
- In your ISR poll the RBIF to know if there is a change on RB<7:4> pins.
- If so make a button scan to detect the pressed key.

Unfortunately can't tell you anything for your display issue since you haven't shared the codes and the configuration of display.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was only using INT0 interrupt to demonstrate the problem (See the note in my original post). The reason I was using INT0-2 is because it immediately tell me which column the key press is coming from and only need to check rows. If I use RB4-7 I would have to check both column and row. Nevertheless, I might give your implementation a try.